# iPhone downloading many small JSON files and storing in DB asynchronously

Tags: iphone, json, core-data, download, afnetworking

I have to download 100 thousand JSONS, each JSON not more than 200 characters. I am using AF networking. Is there a way to encode to reduce the size at the server side and send and i should be able to decode at iPhone side.

Moreover has anyone got a method to download the JSONS and store it in the DB on the background thread.Because when i do that directly the UI thread is blocked. Sample Code would be really helpful.

Need the best way to download the HUGE-JSON and store it in the DB.Thanks!

Comment: You don't have ***a*** HUGE JSON. You have 100,000 tiny JSON's. Combine your JSON's into bigger chunks. 100 thousand HTTP requests will kill the device's battery and take much longer to download. Also gzip the response as @Volker suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For encoding you can, for example, use gzip-compressed data in your http response that will be unpacked by ios automatically without the need to code anything. Just add "Content-Encoding: gzip" to your http response on the server side. On iOS, i think NSURLRequest accepts gzip encoding by default, or you can set

```
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"]
```

Of course you can download the JSONS in the background. A good source for information and example code is here http://iosdevelopmentjournal.com/blog/2013/01/27/running-network-requests-in-the-background/

Comment: Is running the downloading process in BACKGROUND necessary if i am using AFnetworking. I guess it handles those requests in background, dosent it?